# Подскажите программное обеспечение для обучения правописанию

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, грамматика

Я копирайтер, хотел бы научиться правописанию. Есть ли программы для этого?

Comment: Про "?" Вы вообще никогда не слышали?!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, само собой, дискуссионный. Всё зависит от того, что вы именно хотите. В обязанности копирайтера входит написание рекламных текстов, так что для этого специалист должен хорошо знать орфографические, грамматические, стилистические и пунктуационные нормы русского языка. Информации сейчас море, в сети очень много хороших сайтов. Можно учиться на [этом](http://therules.ru/) сайте, а можно попробовать на старой-доброй [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/).